# How to create resource folder for phone landscape + all tablets

Tags: android, gridview

I am doing an app whose main activity consists of a gridview filled with images.

When the gridview is displayed on portrait phones, I want it to have 2 columns.

When it is displayed on landscape mode, or in a tablet (both 7" and 10", landscape and portrait), I want it to display 3 columns.

In the gridview, i set the numColumns property to a resource integer that I called: @integer/column_count. I intend to modify the value of this resource in the appropriate folder.

Since I don't want to unnecessarily duplicate files, is there a way to accomplish this using only 1 extra folder?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Layouts for landscape screens are stored in "layout-lang". Create layouts, for the screens you want in landscape, with the same name as their counterparts.

Comment: Yes, but what I try to do is:

Create 1 folder that targets:

- phone landscape
- all tablet sizes and orientations.

I want to optimize my resources by creating just 1. Is it possible?